# Accessing deeply nested JSON array with Moshi/Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

All I need is the "photo" array.  My JSON looks like this:

```
 {
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": "1000",
    "perpage": 1,
    "total": "1000",
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "44049202615",
        "owner": "159796861@N07",
        "secret": "cb8f476a4d",
        "server": "1958",
        "farm": 2,
        "title": "Murugan",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

I'm new to Moshi/Retrofit.  I saw [this](https://medium.com/@naturalwarren/moshi-made-simple-jsonqualifier-b99559c826ad) but I don't quite understand yet how to make that work.  I thought I could do something quick and dirty to get the values I need so I can continue to build out my app (I'll go back later for a proper implementation).

My quick and dirty idea was this:

```
data class GalleryItem(@Json(name = "title") val caption: String,
                       @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
                       @Json(name = "url_s") val url: String?)

data class Photo(@Json(name = "photo") val galleryItems: List<GalleryItem>)

data class Photos(@Json(name = "photos") val photo: Photo)
```

I thought I could just return a "Photos" from my api and grab the gallery items.  There's no crashes but it's not parsing correctly.  I get the "Photos" object but "Photo" is null.

Any thoughts on how to access the data I need?

Comment: The problem is probably the Json(name) annotation is not applied to the field. Are you using the Kotlin support in Moshi (see the README)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `@Json` annotation [gets ignored in Kotlin classes](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315). The workaround (from the link I just gave) is to use `@field:Json` instead. Try something like this for your data classes:

```
data class ResponseData(
    val photos: Photos
)

data class Photos(
    @field:Json(name = "photo") val galleryItems: List<GalleryItem>
)

data class GalleryItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String
)
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 5):

try this one!

```kotlin
data class Response(
    @Json(name = "photos")
    val photos: Photos,    
    
    @Json(name = "stat")
    val stat: String
)
        
data class Photos(
    @Json(name = "page")
    val page: Int,
        
    @Json(name = "pages")
    val pages: String,
        
    @Json(name = "photo")
    val photosList: List<Photo>
)
        
data class Photo(
    val id: String,
    val owner: String
)
```

Now you can access the photolist using

```
response.photos.photosList
```

You can easily create pojo from json using this tool. Visit this site.
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Thanks, that's getting me closer.  The response has the proper `page` and `pages` but `photosList` is still null.

Comment: Can you try this data class Photos(
            @Json(name = "page")
            val page: Int,

            @Json(name = "pages")
            val pages: String,

            @Json(name = "photo")
            val photosList: List<Photo> = ArrayList()
    )